# Why is the query returning and error because of the var?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, jpa, repository

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepo extends JpaRepository<Stock, Long> {
```

```
    @Query("SELECT stock " +
            "FROM Stock stock " +
            "WHERE stock.name = :name AND stock.date = :date AND stock.id != :id")
    Optional<Stock> findByStockUpdate(String name, LocalDate date, Long id);
}
```

So, with this Repository, I'm getting some erros when running the app:

could not resolve property: name of: com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.model.Stock [SELECT stock FROM com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.model.Stock stock WHERE stock.name = :name AND stock.date = :date AND stock.id != :id]

could not resolve property: name of: com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.model.Stock [SELECT stock FROM com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.model.Stock stock WHERE stock.name = :name AND stock.date = :date AND stock.id != :id]

Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.repository.StockRepo.findByStockUpdate(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Long)!

Error creating bean with name 'stockRepo' defined in com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.repository.StockRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.santanderdevweek.bootcamp.repository.StockRepo.findByStockUpdate(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Long)!

All of them because of the query (imo), need help (sorry for long post).

Comment: what is the mapping for Stock? does it have a name member?

Comment: Hi @Hugo, could you please share the implementation of Stock entity?

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name= "tb_stock")
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "nameStock")
    private String nameStock;

    @Column(name= "price")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name= "date")
    private LocalDate dateStock;

    @Column(name= "variation")
    private Double variation;`

Comment: ```@Component
public class StockMapper {

    public Stock toEntity(StockDTO dto){
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setId(dto.getId());
        stock.setNameStock(dto.getNameStock());
        stock.setPrice(dto.getPrice());
        stock.setVariation(dto.getVariation());
        stock.setDateStock(dto.getDateStock());

        return stock;
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your entity class don't have the field with name 'name' but 'nameStock' instead.

Change name to nameStock in query.

```
@Query("SELECT stock " +
            "FROM Stock stock " +
            "WHERE stock.nameStock = :nameStock AND stock.date = :date AND stock.id != :id")
```